# How to increase the maximum number of requests per user for Youtube Data API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

What is the Maximum number of requests per user for Youtube Data API? Is there a way to increase the maximum number?

My application uses `Playlists: insert` and `PlaylistItems: insert`. I know about maximum number of requests for Youtube Data API. but these api returns `RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED` even though the request limit has not been reached.

So I changed my account and ran the APIs, it worked.

The problem can be avoided by preparing multiple accounts, but it is not solved fundamentally.

Is there a way to increase the maximum number of Youtube Data API requests per user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somedays ago i contacted Google about the same problem you have, and they answered me saying my API key was out of compliance.I think your case is the same, but until now I didn't realized what I did for The API being out of compliance. if someone knows the answer I appreciate.

Comment: Now I got, what happened in my case, they asked me to show The API policy and google policy terms, in some part of my website and also I have a bug that more than 1 YouTubube player video could be played at the same time ( I still need to fix it). The best you can do is to contact google api support, this way they will tell you exactly what is happening.